# How do I get rid of the nullable mark (?) on my variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I'm building a Flutter app with the null safety. I have a problem when I want to give a nullable variable to a function which can't accept a nullable one.
I tried to check if it was null before calling the function but it doesn't work.

```
if (accountsFactory.selected != null){
  _accountBloc?.select.add(accountsFactory.selected);
}
```

In this sample accountFactory.selected is the nullable one (Account?) and _accountBloc?.select is a StreamSink<Account>.

Does anyone know  how I can make this work ? I would like to keep <Account> on my stream if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the null assertion operator `!`, you would want to do something like this:

```
if (accountsFactory.selected != null){
  _accountBloc?.select.add(accountsFactory.selected!); // assert that selected is not null
}
```

more info about null assertion [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator)

if this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes It is ! thanks a lot. I'm pretty new with the null-safety on Flutter and I didn't know this operator.

Comment: https://github.com/michaelsoliman1/intro_to_dart, check this repo, it has a brief and easy introduction to null safety, also you may accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: thank you, I could not accept it due to a time restriction. It's done now. Thank you again.